# Sad music during Omer/3 Weeks

Tags: music, sefirat-ha-omer, three-weeks

Thought of this question and apparently it was posed a few years ago on here but no answer was given so I’ll ask again- can you listen to sad or depressing music during the Omer or more importantly the 3 weeks? The “prohibition” to listen to music comes from not giving yourself pleasure or getting you in a jolly mood as far as I know, so if you listen to a sad song that would make you cry is this allowed?

Comment: If you see an unanswered old question that you're also interested in, you should rather offer a bounty...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maharam Shik YD 368 says that really sad music that brings people to cry should be permitted during Avelus.

It should be noted that this is about sad music not slow music.

During the Omer many are lenient based on R Moshe (OC 1:166) who says the whole prohibition is based on the year around prohibition of music, that at least should be kept during Omer. Therefore, many say slow soothing music is permitted (Rav Schlesinger Shoalin Vedirshin 4:37). The three weeks are more stringent though.

Comment: Rav Moshe forbids music the entire year?!

Comment: @Curious there is an opinion based on the Gemarra that we are permanently in mourning since we lost the Beit haMikdash and so we should ideally never listen to music; since realistically that's beyond the means of most people we don't hold it as normative halacha

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2169/music-not-allowed-the-whole-year