Music for Yom Hashoah
Is it permissable to listen to live music during the Omer for the sake of Yom Hashoah commemoration?

Duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/130320/759

Welcome to MiYodeya Max and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!
