# Sleeping Music during the Three Weeks

Tags: halacha, children-parenting, music, sleep, three-weeks

During the three weeks, may parents put on music that helps their children sleep? Perhaps there is a difference between before Rosh Chodesh Av and after Rosh Chodesh Av.

Comment: Related answer: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1050

Answer (score 2):

Generally, if the music is not for one's specific enjoyment, you can listen to the music. In your scenario, you are not the one listening to the music, anyway - your child is. And, s/he is not even listening for the enjoyment of the music, itself, anyway. Plus, there may even be more leniencies for a child below bar / bat Mitzvah, anyway.

In summary, I wouldn't see a problem, personally, but confirm with your Rav.

See [this article](http://www.dinonline.org/2011/07/18/music-for-exercise-in-three-weeks/) for details.