# Is one allowed to listen to music for therapeutic purposes during sefira and the three weeks?

Tags: medicine, music, mourning-aveilus, sefirat-ha-omer, three-weeks

It has been [scientifically proven](http://www.bbc.com/news/health-12135590) that listening to music helps increase people's dopamine (happiness neurotransmitters) levels by as much as 9%, and as such there is such a thing as [music therapy](http://www.musictherapy.org/about/musictherapy/).

Would one be allowed to listen to music for therapeutic purposes during sefira and the three weeks?

Let's assume that there are no doctors' orders, and that a capella doesn't have the same effect.

Comment: Isn't that the point of the ban? It's a period of mourning, we want to feel the loss that occurred during this time.

Comment: @Salmononius2 Sure, that's not the issue at hand here. I'm not talking about your average person. Someone who needs music therapy probably has some severe mental illness that the music can help with.

Comment: So we're talking something medical? Then why wouldn't it be permitted?

Comment: Interestingly enough, SA does not mention anything about banning music during Sefira. (They may have mentioned a general ban against music at all times b/c of the churban - I don't recall.) Offhand, I think therapeutic reasons allow listening to music. I have to hunt down an article I saw on this a while ago.

Comment: I also saw in a halacha sefer that a depressed person who needs it to feel better can listen. I don't remember the source, so I'm leaving this as a comment.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1050/759

Comment: @Salmononius2 Just because it's medicinal doesn't make it permitted. To bring an extreme example, may one eat pig if that's going to cure a disease without doctors' orders? Obviously this case isn't as extreme, and saying that medicinal reasons without a doctor's order overrides a minhag would be an answer.

Comment: "Someone who needs music therapy probably has some severe mental illness that the music can help with" if you are only talking about treatment for someone severely mentally ill, you should specify that in the question.

Comment: @DanF - SA does not mention anything about banning music during Sefira because he "bans it" in סימן תקס - לעשות זכר לחרבן when he says  וְכֵן גָּזְרוּ שֶׁלֹּא לְנַגֵּן בִּכְלֵי שִׁיר וְכָל מִינֵי זֶמֶר וְכָל מַשְׁמִיעֵי קוֹל שֶׁל שִׁיר לְשַׂמֵּחַ בָּהֶם

Comment: @DannySchoemann I'm aware of that general rule. I forgot to mention that in my comment.

Comment: While I haven't located a written opinion on on this topic, I think many rabbanim who view the source of the prohibition in the first place and it's various interpretations and modifications over time will probably find a leniency to allow music for severe medical conditions - esp. ones that can otherwise prevent long-term damage or worsening of the current conditions.

Comment: Who says it's ossur to listen to music during sefira?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R’ Shlomo Zalman Auerbach (Halichos Shlomo, Sefiras Haomer 11:n14) writes that one who will become overly upset without music may listen to recordings. ([source](http://doseofhalacha.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/music-during-sefira.html))